# Как получить выбранный текст из spinner если он построен на основе cursorAdapter

Tags: android, android-spinner

Пытаюсь получить текст пункта из Spinner, который был построен на основе CursorAdapter:

```
String text = spCategory.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Этот метод возвращает "**android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@435b9ba0**"

Получить нужное значение получается следующим образом:

```
String text = ((TextView) spCategory.getSelectedView().findViewById(R.id.item_categories_tv_name)).getText().toString();
```

Но это как-то не красиво.
Пробовал переопределить *convertToString(Cursor cursor)* в CursorAdapter,
результат тот же. Есть ли какой-то более изящный способ решения этой задачи?

Comment: @peter Спасибо, все заработало.

Answer (score 1):

`getItem()` возвращает объект `Cursor`, поэтому нужную строку надо получить из этого курсора:

```
spCategory.getSelectedItem().getString(<номер колонки с текстом для спиннера>);
```