# Неверные значения при получение данных из Spinner (Android)

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-spinner

В Android загружаю данные в Spinner из бд. Необходимо получить строчку, которую пользователь выбрал в Spinner. При привидении значения к строке с помощью toString получается не то. Почему?
Вот код:

```
String deg;
Spinner degreeSpinner;
degreeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                deg = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
                if (cam!="") {
                    //получаем id
                    int id_cam = SubscriptionHelper.getIdCampus(db, cam);
                    int id_deg = SubscriptionHelper.getIdDegree(db, deg);
                    proSp(id_cam, id_deg);
                }
            }
```

Переменная deg после прохождения 6 строчки имеет следующее значение:

```
"deg=android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@d3e005a"
```

Что я делаю не так и как преобразовать получаемые значения в String?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/712412/177345

Comment: спасибо, разобралась!